# The "difference" of two ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $\alpha ,\beta ,\delta$ be ordinals such that $\alpha < \beta$, prove that there is $\delta \leq \beta$ such that $\alpha+\delta = \beta$ ?

I know that if $\beta$ is cardinal then we can take $\delta=\beta$.

Comment: Hint: look at the order type $\{\xi\mid \alpha\leq\xi<\beta\}$

Comment: The works, but $\delta + \alpha = \beta$ may not.